# Alert when value in PHP table changes

Tags: javascript, php

I have two sheets. The control displays a list of job details that also contains a column that echos the notes on the active job, and the other sheet is where the operator can attach a note.

What I need to do is alert the user on the control page that the note for a job has been changed, which would happen after the operator submits the note.
Currently, I have a cell that highlights red when there is a note present, but want to actively send an alert when there is a new note.

I've tried an `onChange()` function but it wouldn't alert until I made an input field and changed it myself on the control page. I also tried the `.change` function but that didn't work either.

The query sent from the operator page to the SQL database is:

```
UPDATE operations
    SET notes=$notes
    WHERE jobID=$jobID
      AND operation=$operation"
```

The code to echo the red cell on the control page is this PHP:

```
$conN = mysqli_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER);

if (!$conN) {
   die('Could not connect: ' . mysqli_error($conN));
} // Check Connection

mysqli_select_db($conN,"jms");

$jid = $row['jobID'];
$opn = $row['operation'];
$highlight = mysqli_query($conN,
    "SELECT notes FROM operations WHERE jobID=$jid AND operation=$opn"
);

while ($data = mysqli_fetch_array($highlight))

    if (isset($data['notes']) && $data['notes'] != "") {

        echo "<td id='notes' style='background-color:red;width:1%;'>" .
          "<input class='target' type='text' value='" .
          $data["notes"]. "' >" . "</td>";

    } else {

        echo "<td style='background-color:white;width:1%;'>" . "</td>";

    }

echo "</tr>"; // End the row
$index++;
```

While the cell that is being echo'd as red has an `if (isset())` function to display red if there is a note in the database for the specific job and operation.

EDIT:
Here is the Javascript I've been trying to call with the onChange function:

```
function newNote() {
var jobID = "X";
var operation = "Y";
alert("New note added to Job No. "+jobID+" at Operation No. "+operation);
}
```

As you can see, its a very simple piece of script, so I ended up just simplifying the process and using a simple alert of text as a test.

Comment: Please provide the code you talk about.

Comment: This is awfully broad and we have lot's of ideas.

Comment: @JayBlanchard, I'm open for all ideas.

Comment: @eksepshon Where is the Javascript?  The purpose of SO isn't to code ready-made solutions, but to help resolve problems.  Please provide a [mcve] of the problem.

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using parameterized queries and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you have created a severe [SQL injection bug](http://bobby-tables.com/).

Answer (score 1):

you can do it by JQuery or JavaScript , what you need is to immediately detect any change of DB records by sending request and then receiving response   .

use ajax function by either jQuery or java script and make the post target your mentioned control page , and alert the response.

one example by jquery :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 $.ajax({
        type: "POST", 
        url: "yourcontrolpage",
        data: { jid: jid ,opn:opn},

        success: function(html) {

         alert(html);

             } 
}); });
```

for example , you can retrieve the number of records or the latest record , so in the next request you can determine whether there is a change so alert will be executed or there is no change so nothing will be happened

Comment: I'm sorry, I found this very confusing so when I tried to implement it, it didn't work and I'm sure I just didn't do it correctly.

Comment: i understand , ok , include the JQuery library between head tags then write this code after body tag and consider the two post varibales or just one,so they will go directly to target page then receive them their as post  variables and do select from your table in general to calculate the records  and echo the result which will come as response so you can use it again in next post to determine the status